# Sometimes Date() returns January 1st

Tags: ios, swift, date

Sometimes I'm experiencing the following issue and I've been struggling with it for months now - also couldn't find any solutions yet:

I'm creating a new `Date()` object but it's not today's date, but this year's January 1st.

This happens both on Simulator and actual devices and the only way to fix it is to use `NSDate()` instead. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
let date = Date()
print(date) // prints 2019-12-31 22:00:00 +0000 - Jan 1st adjusted to CEST timezone

let date = NSDate()
print(date) // prints 2020-07-29 07:50:25 +0000
```

Edit: Updated with screenshot

[image]

Comment: Do you have your own Date type defined? What happens if you do `let date = Foundation.Date()`?

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a custom Date type. Unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Ok but then you need to post more info on how to reproduce this or more context about how it happens or this question is almost impossible to answer.